# Replacing multiple punctuation marks in a column of data

Tags: r, string, replace, gsub

Column in a df:

```
chr10:123453:A:C
chr10:2345543:TTTG:CG
chr10:3454757:G:C
chr10:4567875765:C:G
```

Desired output:

```
chr10:123453_A/C
chr10:2345543_TTTG/CG
chr10:3454757_G/C
chr10:4567875765_C/G
```

I think I could use stingsplit but I wanted to try and do it all in a R oneliner. Any ideas would be greatly welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
gsub(":([A-Z]+):([A-Z]+)$", "_\\1/\\2", x, perl = TRUE)
[1] "chr10:123453_A/C"      "chr10:2345543_TTTG/CG"
```

Here we use backreference twice: `\\1` recollects what's between the pre-ultimate and the ultimate `:`, whereas `\\2` recollects what's after the ultimate `:`.

Data:

```
x <- c("chr10:123453:A:C","chr10:2345543:TTTG:CG")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to both reply and give a clear explanation, that backrefence is a great tip! Thanks again!